# Meteor server close socket with message to client

Tags: meteor

Without too many details, I'm building an app where users join rooms, and I need to be able to boot them from a room, relying on client-side code as little as possible.

What's the best way to do this?

This means ending an arbitrary user's subscription. The only place I've found to stop a subscription from the server is in the publish() function, which is only called once per subscription. So I put an event listener in there listening for an emission unique to that connection. This means I have an event listener for **every** subscription ...

At any rate, the event is firing, and inside there, I tried:

```
this._session.socket.close(1, 'You have been kicked');
```

This closes the socket, but I can't find a way to listen to that event on the client to identify the kick, without listening on all disconnections.

There has to be a way to do this that I'm overlooking.

Thanks.

Comment: your question is a bit too abstract to be answered like that. There are probably a bunch of ways you could do that, but I don't think anyone wants to sit down and just write that code for you. messing with sockets directly doesn't seem like a very meteor way of doing this. if you really don't want to use much client code, then maybe meteor is not the right choice here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the database for this.

```
Rooms.update(roomId, {$pull: {members: userId}});
```

Then, make sure the publication only publishes rooms where the user is a member, and make sure the method for sending a message to a room checks the user is a member as well.